# Concatenar texto a uma coluna já existente SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho o seguinte **SQL**:

```
UPDATE tabela SET peso = peso "KG"
```

Eu preciso adicionar ao campo peso, a tag *KG*, porém, se eu fizer da forma que eu expus, não dá certo. Como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Depende do SGBD, no SQLServer aceita o + para concatenar as strings, já no SQLite eu acho que é com |

Comment: @AndréBaill Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize aspas simples para concatenar o texto `'KG'`

**SQL SERVER:**

Além da função [CONCAT()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) você pode utilizar o `+` para concatenar o valor atual da coluna com *KG*:

```
UPDATE tabela SET peso = peso + 'KG'
```

**SQLite:**

Utilize o `||` para [concatenar](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/concatenate.php), o `CONCAT` aqui não funciona.

```
UPDATE Tabela Set Coluna = Coluna || 'KG'
```

**MySQL:**

Utilize [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE tabela SET peso = CONCAT(peso, 'KG');
```

Obs.: Também é possível fazer com `||` como no *SQLite* mas para isso você deve configurar o *MySQL* para aceitar, setando `sql_mode` para `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`.

**PostgreSQL:**

Além da função [CONCAT()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) você pode utilizar o `||` para concatenar.

```
UPDATE Tabela Set Coluna = Coluna || 'KG'
```

**Oracle:**

Além da função [CONCAT()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) você pode utilizar o `||` para concatenar.

```
UPDATE Tabela Set Coluna = Coluna || 'KG'
```

Todos os comandos acima foram testados no *SQLFiddle*.

Comment: Tem SGBD pode não entender "somas" de string

Comment: Resposta atualizada

Comment: Que resposta! Ficou ótima

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que concatenar o que está armazenado mais a `tag` KG:

```
UPDATE tabela SET peso = CONCAT(peso, " KG");
```

Comment: Matou a charada! Top top!